# Package does not exist in this plugin

Tags: eclipse, pde

I tried importing a plugin as a source project in my workspace. Now I am getting a package does not exist in this plugin error in the Manifest.mf file. But the packages do exist in the source folder of the same plugin. What could be the issue? I tried googling but I could find only these kind of errors when the package is coming from a different eclipse project. Pls give me some light on this

[image: Image showing my package structure]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2lrE.png

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: xyz Plug-in 2.1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.abc.xyz
Bundle-Version: 2.1.0
Bundle-ClassPath: xyz.jar
Bundle-Activator: com.abc.xyz.xyzPlugin
Bundle-Vendor: FHG
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Export-Package: xyz.common,
 xyz.common.pattern,
 xyz.cursor,
 xyz.dm.common,
 xyz.dom,
 xyz.dom.bootModel,
 xyz.dom.exception,
 xyz.dom.x,
 xyz.errmsg,
 xyz.eventHandling,
 xyz.mof,
 xyz.mof.exception,
 xyz.mof.x,
 xyz.versioning.extent,
 xyz.versioning.versionstore,
 com.CH_co.cryptx,
 com.CH_co.util,
 com.abc.xyz,
 com.abc.xyz.uuid,
 com.tools,
 config,
 mdd.delta.model,
 mdd.diffmerge,
 mdd.diffmerge.event,
 mdd.model,
 transactionHandling,
 uuidGenerator
Eclipse-AutoStart: true
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.abc.mdd.common
```

This is the manifest.mf file

Comment: Can you give us concrete details, such as the contents of the manifest and the layout of the project, which package it's complaining about, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer I found was a bit strange and I am unable to find the logic behind it. I deleted the errors in the Problems view and restarted the eclipse in clean mode. It started working. Pls let me know what could be the reason behind it

Comment: While I cannot tell you why this is so, I just wanted to thank you for helping me with this annoying problem.
And yes: There doesen't seem to be any logic behind it.

Btw: I am using Eclipse Neon3, just for the record.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me too - thank you! In my case, I was trying to use Export-Classpath with a file placed in the lib/ directory under the project directory. For some reason, eclipse deleted that directory and the jar file inside it. I recreated the directory and its jar file and rebuilt the project but the problem stayed. I deleted the error message (seems a strange thing to do!) then restarted eclipse with the -clean command line option. This time it built OK. I suspect there was some kind of race condition but it seems to me like a bug in how eclipse handles its caches.

Comment: Nine and a half years later and the above solution is still relevant.  Glad I stumbled across this seeing I was completely stumped.  Thank you!

Comment: Yep, deleting lib folder and let eclipse create again is working.